# PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation in cosmosdb delete operaiton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to delete a document from Cosmos DB

My code is like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeletePartner(string id)
        {
            var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            try
            {

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }


                var customers = await CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreCustomer.Query().Where(x=> x.PartnerId == id).ToListAsync();
                var userStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreUser;
                var users = await userStore.Query().Where(x => x.PartnerId == id).ToListAsync(); ;

                if (customers.Count> 0 || users.Count>0)
                {
                    return BadRequest("You cant delete partners with existing customers or users");
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = await CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStorePartner.RemoveByIdAsync(id, "/CosmosEntityName");
                    return Ok(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
                };

                telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
                return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
            }
        }
    }



[SharedCosmosCollection("shared")]
    public class Partner : ISharedCosmosEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Partner id
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner name
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner contact name
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerContact { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner contact phone
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerPhone { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner contact Office 365 domain
        /// </summary>
        public string PartnerDomain { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner type, silver, gold or platinum
        /// </summary>
        [ValidEnumValue]
        public PartnerType PartnerType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner start date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Partner end date
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parter enabled
        /// </summary>
        public bool  Enabled { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// CosmosEntityname
        /// </summary>
        [CosmosPartitionKey]
        public string CosmosEntityName { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Partner type Enum
    /// </summary>
    public enum PartnerType
    {
        ///Silver
        Silver,
        ///Gold
        Gold,
        ///Platinum
        Platinum
    }
```

But I got this error:
PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation

I was trying to send as string "/CosmosEntityName" as second parameter, but it doesnt work

I am using Cosmonaut

Comment: `RemoveByIdAsync` is not part of the Cosmos DB SDK, could you share which is the code for that method and how it is calling the Cosmos DB SDK?

Comment: its part of Cosmonaut, which is the most widely used third party sdk for cosmosdb

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the request options. For example, if your collection is partitioned by CosmosEntityName;

```
await this.documentClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(productDocument._self, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(productDocument.CosmosEntityName) });
```

EDIT:

Here's what you need with [Cosmonaut SDK](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/issues/65)

> You need to provide the partition key value not the partition key
>   definition when you delete. Your delete request should look like this,
>   assuming the id is your partition key.

```
var deleted = await this._cosmonautClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(this._databaseName, collectionName, message.Id, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(message.Id) });
```

Comment: I dont have self, in my entity.

Comment: why cosmonaut? you can directly use the cosmosdb sdk. However i updated my answer

Comment: because I have used cosmonaut for over 2 years and it has better over the official SDK, however the method call is very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the **value** of the partition key of the element you want to delete as second parameter, not the path and attribute name.

```
var result = await CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStorePartner.RemoveByIdAsync(id, "<partition key value for that id>");
```

Since the attribute you have defined as PK is `CosmosEntityName`, you need that attribute's value for that document.