# PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation in CosmosDB delete operation using DocumentClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, documentclient

I am trying to delete an item from a container of Cosmos DB database from azure function.
But I am getting this error **PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.** I also investigated [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620602/partitionkey-value-must-be-supplied-for-this-operation-in-cosmosdb-delete-operai) but didn't get any luck from there.

Below is my code -

```
public class Item{
    public Item(){}
    public string id {get; set;}
}

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://***.documents.azure.com:443/"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key"));

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var updated = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(requestBody);
    
    var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
    var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("Test_DB", "Test_Table");
  
    var document = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, option).Where(t => t.Id == updated.id)
        .AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

    log.LogInformation("Total Incentive : " + document.GetPropertyValue<string>("id"));

    if (document == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundResult();
    }

    log.LogInformation("Total Incentive : " + document.SelfLink);
    log.LogInformation("Total Incentive : " + document.Id);

    await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink);
  
    //await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(document);

    return new OkObjectResult("Deleted");
}
```

After googling I realized that I need to provide a partition key value as the second parameter in **DeleteDocumentAsync()** like below. But I am **in a fix** how to provide that partition key value to that function.

```
await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.SelfLink,
  new Requestoptions
  {
    PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey("33333")
  }
)
```

**DB Name:** Test_DB

**Table Name:** Test_Table

**Partition Key:** /testCategory

An example element of my Test_Table which I am trying to delete is:

```
{
    "id": "3f614t4e-q85f-4357-8393-a0b3542db4e1",
    "Email": "testuser@test.com",
    "Name": "Test User",
    "_rid": "XNMBANxVc8oIAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/XNMOXA==/colls/TNMNANyVc9o=/docs/XNMBANxVc8oIZZAAAAAAPP==/",
    "_etag": "\"450031d4-0000-0300-0000-60cb36470000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1623930439
}
```

Can anyone help me how to put that partition key in the azure function code? Or how to adjust the table of the database?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: So essentially you have a document without partition key. Correct?

Comment: Any reason you're using the v2 SDK? The v3 SDK has superseded and is best going forward.

Comment: Can you try by using `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey.None`?

Comment: @GauravMantri It's working. Thanks. What is the best practice? Keeping a testCategory attribute in every element of the table and then supply that attribute as the partition key, Is it?

Comment: When you create the collection yous hould specify the partition key, this could be the Id property.  When deleting the item you can specify a partition key using the same property.

Comment: @NoahStahl Can you please provide the v3 SDK resource? Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer and provided some more details. HTH.

Comment: Deleting using v3 SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.deleteitemstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, when the partition key is not specified in the document, you can use `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey.None` as partition key value for deletes and updates.

In Cosmos DB, each document must have a value specified for the partition key attribute (`testCategory` in your case) when you create a document. However, Cosmos DB will not complain if you don't specify a value. It simply puts such documents in a special partition that can be accessed by specifying `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey.None` in the methods where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
await _client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(_databaseId, CollectionId, id), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**