# Updating Cosmos DB update record with C#

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use Cosmos DB partial document update. But I can not get it to work.

I have a model like this:

```
public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string FamilyName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

The method I am using

```
public async Task UpdateFirstName(string id, String firstName)
{
    try
    {
        var  response = await personContainer.PatchItemAsync<Person>(
                 id: id,
                 partitionKey: new PartitionKey("/id"),
                 patchOperations: new[] {
                     PatchOperation.Replace("/firstName", firstName)
                 }
            );

        var updated = response.Resource;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It keeps crashing out on the update and, throwing the following error

> Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 9da753ee-e64c-4ec2-a973-df7fae97b485;
> Reason: (
> Errors : [
> "Resource Not Found. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"
> ]);

My Cosmos package is `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` 3.35.1

Elsewhere I have written code that does a get all and a get by Id, and they are working and Cosmos DB is running.

I have tried

```
partitionKey: new PartitionKey("/id"),

partitionKey: new PartitionKey("@id"),

partitionKey: new PartitionKey("id"),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation in cosmosdb delete operaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620602/partitionkey-value-must-be-supplied-for-this-operation-in-cosmosdb-delete-operai)

Answer (score 2):

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58715281/5641598 regarding the problem with the `partitionKey` parameter. You need to use:

```
new PartitionKey(id)
```

Your model also does not match the property you are patching. You are patching `firstName`:

```
PatchOperation.Replace("/firstName", firstName)
```

But your model has `FirstName` (casing is different):

```
public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string FamilyName { get; set; } = "";
 
}
```

Either match the casing or use Json decorators (such as `[JsonProperty("firstName")]`) to configure the casing of the property when serialized.